# Linux bash script for watching file changes -> how do I get changed file names

Tags: linux, bash, shell, watch

I want to edit this watch script by Mike Mullin: https://gist.github.com/mikesmullin/6401258 to get the name of a changed file. It only seems to check for data integrity of the whole file list:

```
update_sha() {
sha=`ls -lR --time-style=full-iso $path | sha1sum`
}
```

Which get's compared with the old list:

```
compare() {
  update_sha
  if [[ $sha != $previous_sha ]] ; then
    echo -n "change detected,"
    build
    previous_sha=$sha
  else
    echo -n .
  fi
}
```

If I understand it correct, it only checks if there is ANY change happening, but not which file exactly is changed.
Is there still a way to get the individual name of the file that was changed?

Comment: The script you show is controlling a single file, identified by "$path".

Comment: @pasabaporaqui: the script hashes `ls -lr $path`, so it is working on the recursive directory listing, not a single file.

Comment: Sorry, it is true, but only one sha sum is used and stored, all them are considered a packet.

Comment: @pasaba: precisely the motive of the OP :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can I suggest a different aproach? Use tools "inotifywait". See this link as reference: https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes

Answer (score 3):

In order to find out what changes have been made to the directory tree, you'd need to save the entire output of the `ls -lr`, and not just the checksum. For a directory tree of up to a few million files, that shouldn't be too problematic, but for very large trees, you might want to try a different approach.

Once you know that two directory listings differ, you can use the `diff` utility to find the differences. Gnu diff provides a very customizable mechanism for formatting the diff report.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrote this I think it might work:

```
for name in $(find . -type f)
do 
    sha1sumstr="$(sha1sum $name)"
    sha1sum_sep=($sha1sumstr)
    sha1="${sha1sum_sep[0]}"
    fp="${sha1sum_sep[1]}"
    printf "\nChecking: %s with filepath %s\n" $sha1 $fp
    checkstr="$(grep -h $sha1 ../prev_check)"
    checkarr=($checkstr)
    if [ "$checkstr" == "$sha1sumstr" ]; then
      printf "\nnochange\n"
    else
      printf "Possibly new file:\nFrom: %s\n  To: %s\n" "$checkstr" "$sha1sumstr"
      if [ "${checkarr[1]}" == "$fp" ]; then
        printf "Filname not changed\n"
      else
        checkname="$(grep -h $fp ../prev_check)"
        if [ -n  "$checkname" ]; then
            printf "$checkname\n" 
            printf "Name is the same\n"
        else
            printf "Name Changed: %s\n" "$fp"
        fi
      fi
    fi
    echo "$sha1sumstr" >> ../new_check
done
mv ../new_check ../prev_check
```

Sample output after I saved changes to the script:

```
bob@squids:~/Development/fileshare/testdir$ ./check_name_change.sh 

Checking: a8fdc205a9f19cc1c7507a60c4f01b13d11d7fd0 with filepath ./test.txt

nochange

Checking: c97a03c8d412ad7a4579fa59b33056253e8113a3 with filepath ./testchilddir/test.txt

nochange

Checking: b8cf155a4ca493f0e8c598e92f212947c13b8842 with filepath ./check_name_change.sh
Possibly new file:
From: 
  To: b8cf155a4ca493f0e8c598e92f212947c13b8842  ./check_name_change.sh
f46261e680c1f28d7537ac332c02e23fa2e7382b  ./check_name_change.sh
Name is the same
```

Sample output after changing the name of `test.txt` to `changed.txt`:

```
bob@squids:~/Development/fileshare/testdir$ ./check_name_change.sh 

Checking: c97a03c8d412ad7a4579fa59b33056253e8113a3 with filepath ./testchilddir/test.txt

nochange

Checking: b8cf155a4ca493f0e8c598e92f212947c13b8842 with filepath ./check_name_change.sh

nochange

Checking: a8fdc205a9f19cc1c7507a60c4f01b13d11d7fd0 with filepath ./changed.txt
Possibly new file:
From: a8fdc205a9f19cc1c7507a60c4f01b13d11d7fd0  ./test.txt
  To: a8fdc205a9f19cc1c7507a60c4f01b13d11d7fd0  ./changed.txt
Name Changed: ./changed.txt
```

It will be a slow solution if checking a lot of files.